# Microsoft Access: Complex string search to update field in another table

Tags: parsing, ms-access, recordset

I have a table that is linked to Access to return the results of emails into a folder.  All of the emails being returned will be answering the same questions.  I need to parse this email body text from this table and update several fields of another table with this data. The problem is that the linked table brings the text in super messy.  Even though I have the email that is being returned all nicely formatted in a table, it comes back into access a hot mess full of extra spacing.  I want to open a recordset based on the linked table (LinkTable), and then parse the LinkTable.Body field somehow so I can update another table with clean data.  The data that is coming back into LinkTable looks like this:

Permit? (Note: if yes, provide specific permit type in Additional Requirements section)

```
No
```

Phytosanitary Certificate? (Note: if recommended, input No and complete Additional Requirements section)

```
Yes
```

Additional Requirements: if not applicable, indicate NA or leave blank (Type of permit required, container labeling, other agency documents, other)

```
Double containment, The labeling or declaration must provide the following information: -The kind, variety, and origin of each lot of seed -The designation “hybrid” when the lot contains hybrid seed -If the seed was treated, the name of the substance or p
```

The answer of the first two should either be yes or no, so I figured I could set up code with case statements and based on a match I should place yes or no in the corresponding field in my real table (not sure how to deal with the extra spaces here),  The third one could have any number of responses, but it is the last question so anything after the "(Type of permit required, container labeling, other agency documents, other)" could be taken and placed in the other table.  Does anyone have any ideas how I could set this up?  I am at a bit of a loss, especially with how to deal with all of the extra spaces and how to grab all of the text after the Additional Requirements paragraph.  Thank you in advance!

My select statement to get the body text looks like this:

```
Set rst1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Subject, Contents FROM LinkTable WHERE Subject like '*1710'")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, one is using `Instr()` and `Len()` to find beginning and end of the fixed questions, then `Mid()` to extract the answers.

But I think using `Split()` is easier. It's best explained with commented code.

```vb
Public Sub TheParsing()

    ' A string constant that you expect to never come up in the Contents, used as separator for Split()
    Const strSeparator = "##||##"

    Dim rst1  As Recordset
    Dim S As String
    Dim arAnswers As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    S = Nz(rst1!Contents, "")
    ' Replace all the constant parts (questions) with the separator
    S = Replace(S, "Permit? (Note: if yes, provide specific permit type in Additional Requirements section)", strSeparator)
    ' etc. for the other questions

    ' Split the remaining string into a 0-based array with the answers
    arAnswers = Split(S, strSeparator)

    ' arAnswers(0) contains everything before the first question (probably ""), ignore that.
    ' Check that there are 3 answers
    If UBound(arAnswers) <> 3 Then
        ' Houston, we have a problem
        Stop
    Else
        For i = 1 To 3
            ' Extract each answer
            S = arAnswers(i)
            ' Remove whitespace: CrLf, Tab
            S = Replace(S, vbCrLf, "")
            S = Replace(S, vbTab, "")
            ' Trim the remaining string
            S = Trim(S)

            ' Now you have the cleaned up string and can use it
            Select Case i
                Case 1: strPermit = S
                Case 2: strCertificate = S
                Case 3: strRequirements = S
            End Select
        Next i
    End If

    rst1.MoveNext
    ' etc

End Sub
```

This will fail if the constant parts (the questions) have been altered. But so will all other straightforward methods.

Comment: Thank you so much for the guidance!